# vuejs - without any node mentioned

Tags: django, vue.js

I am working on Django (Python based Web Framework) project with Vue.js as my front-end choice.

Almost all articles about Vuejs mention Node - at least to start development server. I am looking for some good read which talks only about Vue.js and architecture part of the application.  How to and where to create those store, components, routes files? What should be ideal location/directory structure to start Vuejs - without bothering about Node part of it.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Node at all to run Vue. NodeJs is Javascript serverside, Vue is clientside, therefore interpreted by the browser. You can simply use [Vue via CDN](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#CDN) and follow along all [the tutorials](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/133/How-to-Install-Vue-2---Through-CDN,-NPM-and-the-Vue-CLI) you find on the web or follow the extensive [Vue documentation/reference](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html).
What you probably mean is the usage of NPM to install e.g. vue-cli and using it as a development server with for example webpack, which isn't using node.js, but using npm, the package manager for javascript.

Comment: Yes, use of npm is what troubles me every now and then :)